# What is openCL equivalent for this cuda "cudaMallocPitch "code.?

Tags: visual-c++, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

My PC has an AMD processor with an ATI 3200 GPU which doesn't support OpenCL. The rest of the codes all running by "Falling back to CPU itself".

I am converting one of the code from CUDA to OpenCL but stuck in some particular part for which there is no exact conversion code in OpenCL. since i have less experience in OpenCL I can't make out this, please suggest me some solution if any of you think will work,

The CUDA code is,

```
size_t pitch = 0;   
cudaError error = cudaMallocPitch((void**)&gpu_data, (size_t*)&pitch, 
                          instances->cols * sizeof(float), instances->rows);

for( int i = 0; i < instances->rows; i++ ){ 
    error = cudaMemcpy((void*)(gpu_data + (pitch/sizeof(float))*i), 
                       (void*)(instances->data + (instances->cols*i)), 
                       instances->cols * sizeof(float) ,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

If I remove the pitch value from the above I end up with an problem which doesn't write to the device memory "gpu_data".

Somebody please convert this code to OpenCL and reply. I have converted it to OpenCL, but its not working and the data is not written to "gpu_data". My converted OpenCL code is

```
gpu_data = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, ((instances->cols)*(instances->rows))*sizeof(float), NULL, &ret);
for( int i = 0; i < instances->rows; i++ ){ 
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, gpu_data, CL_TRUE, 0, ((instances->cols)*(instances->rows))*sizeof(float),(void*)(instances->data + (instances->cols*i)) , 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Sometimes it runs well for this code and gets stuck in the reading part i.e.

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, gpu_data, CL_TRUE, 0,sizeof( float ) * instances->cols* 1 , instances->data, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

overhere. And it gives error like

> Unhandled exception at 0x10001098 in CL_kmeans.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction.

when break is pressed , it gives:

> No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.

while debugging. In the call stack it is displaying:

> OCL8CA9.tmp.dll!10001098()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for OCL8CA9.tmp.dll]
>       amdocl.dll!5c39de16()

I really dont know what it means. someone please help me to rid of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in the CUDA code you're doing a horribly inefficient thing to copy the data. The CUDA runtime has the function `cudaMemcpy2D` that does exactly what you are trying to do by looping over different rows.

What `cudaMallocPitch` does is to compute an optimal pitch (= distance in byte between rows in a 2D array) such that each new row begins at an address that is optimal for coalescing, and then allocates a memory area as large as pitch times the number of rows you specify. You can emulate the same thing in OpenCL by first computing the optimal pitch and then doing the allocation of the correct size.

The optimal pitch is computed by (1) getting the base address alignment preference for your card (CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN property with clGetDeviceInfo: note that the returned value is in bits, so you have to divide by 8 to get it in bytes); let's call this `base` (2) find the largest multiple of `base` that is no less than your natural data pitch (sizeof(type) times number of columns); this will be your `pitch`.

You then allocate `pitch` times number of rows bytes, and pass the `pitch` information to kernels.

Also, when copying data from the host to the device and converesely, you want to use `clEnqueue{Read,Write}BufferRect`, that are specifically designed to copy 2D data (they are the counterparts to `cudaMemcpy2D`).